# Different env-file but same yml with Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I find it quite common that I have multiple environments (for example test and prod) but the Docker containers that I wish to start are the same in both environments. The only difference is the application configuration which I want to specify using an `env-file`.  Since I have multiple containers and dependencies between them I want to use [docker-compose](https://github.com/docker/compose). But afaik I can only specify an `env-file` inside the `docker-compose.yml` file (see [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#env_file)). If this is the case then I need to clone my original `docker-compose.yml` to two different files  (one for test and one for prod) just to point to different env files. This means that I have to maintain two `docker-compose.yml` files instead of one and if I make any changes I need to update both files.

Is this really according to design? Why won't `docker-compose` let me specify `--env-file` when I do `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose run`?

Comment: If you're trying to specify on the command line an environment file for docker compose different from its default .env file, please see this issue: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4841

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**See Update #2 below. This is now possible!**

This is a much requested feature of Docker Compose. Unfortunately, the answer at the moment is that you can't. I'd recommend subscribing to these GitHub issues to get a better idea when and if this feature gets implemented:

- https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/495
- https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/76
- https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/845

Issue #495 is actually the most commented in their issue repository at the moment. You are definitely not alone in wanting to do this.

Update:

The latest issue tracking is at https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1377.

Update #2:

This functionality has been merged and is available as of Docker Compose 1.5.0. See https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/129092b7/docs/yml.md#variable-substitution for usage information.

Comment: Thanks, added link to original answer.

Comment: @AndyShinn the original question was for a command-line option to specify an environment file, but that has NOT yet appeared in docker-compose, not even in latest v1.16.1. Not downvoting, but I find update #2 above VERY confusing.

Comment: Just make `env-file` an environment variable: `MYENVFILE=production.env docker-compose up`

Answer (score 7):

It isn't a direct inclusion from the command line, but if you need a work-around before [the #1765 merge](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/1765) (the fix for [#1377](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1377)) makes it into a release, you can use the [`extends` directive](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) along with the [`env_file` directive](https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#env-file). For convenience, the files from the simple examples below are reproduced in [this repository](https://github.com/posita/docker-compose-extends-env).

### Stupid simple example

#### `base.yml`

```yml
base:
    image: busybox
    command: bash -c 'echo "${WHO:-Simon} says, \"${SHOUTOUT:-Silence is golden.}\""'
```

#### `one.env`

```sh
WHO=Da Schwartz
SHOUTOUT=Get to...
```

#### `one_glue.yml`

```yml
one:
    extends:
        file: base.yml
        service: base
    env_file:
        - one.env
```

#### `two.env`

```sh
WHO=Da Schwartz
SHOUTOUT=...da choppa!
```

#### `two_glue.yml`

```yml
two:
    extends:
        file: base.yml
        service: base
    env_file:
        - two.env
```

#### Use

```sh
% for i in base one_glue two_glue ; do docker-compose --file "${i}.yml" up ; done
Recreating dockercomposeextendsenv_base_1...
Attaching to dockercomposeextendsenv_base_1
base_1 | Simon says, "Silence is golden."
dockercomposeextendsenv_base_1 exited with code 0
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Recreating dockercomposeextendsenv_one_1...
Attaching to dockercomposeextendsenv_one_1
one_1 | Da Schwartz says, "Get to..."
dockercomposeextendsenv_one_1 exited with code 0
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Recreating dockercomposeextendsenv_two_1...
Attaching to dockercomposeextendsenv_two_1
two_1 | Da Schwartz says, "...da choppa!"
dockercomposeextendsenv_two_1 exited with code 0
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
```

### Even simplerer example

The above works if you benefit from using `.env` files. If you aren't so limited, you could keep the environment variable settings in the environment-specific "glue" `.yml` files:

#### `red_glue.yml`

```yml
red:
    extends:
        file: base.yml
        service: base
    environment:
        - WHO=Stallion
        - SHOUTOUT=I am...
```

#### `blue_glue.yml`

```yml
blue:
    extends:
        file: base.yml
        service: base
    environment:
        - WHO=Stallion
        - SHOUTOUT=...the law!
```

#### Use

```sh
% for i in red_glue blue_glue ; do docker-compose --file "${i}.yml" up ; done
Creating dockercomposeextendsenv_red_1...
Attaching to dockercomposeextendsenv_red_1
red_1 | Stallion says, "I am..."
dockercomposeextendsenv_red_1 exited with code 0
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Creating dockercomposeextendsenv_blue_1...
Attaching to dockercomposeextendsenv_blue_1
blue_1 | Stallion says, "...the law!"
dockercomposeextendsenv_blue_1 exited with code 0
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
```

### A little more complicated

For what it's worth, the approach described in this answer allows for different `.env` files on a per-instance basis, rather than per-invocation/environment. (I'm not sure how beneficial this is in practice, however.) In other words, you could do something like this:

#### `testing.yml`

```yml
# Only instance1 and instance2 are needed for testing

instance1:
    extends:
        file: base.yml
        service: base
    env_file:
        - test.env # environment-specific
        - instance1_test.env # instance-specific

instance2:
    extends:
        file: base.yml
        service: base
    env_file:
        - test.env
        - instance2_test.env
```

#### `production.yml`

```yml
# All four instances are used for production

instance1:
    extends:
        file: base.yml
        service: base
    env_file:
        - prod.env # environment-specific
        - instance1_prod.env # instance-specific

instance2:
    extends:
        file: base.yml
        service: base
    env_file:
        - prod.env
        - instance2_prod.env

instance3:
    extends:
        file: base.yml
        service: base
    env_file:
        - prod.env
        - instance3_prod.env

instance4:
    extends:
        file: base.yml
        service: base
    env_file:
        - prod.env
        - instance4_prod.env
```

You can start to see that `extends` is pretty powerful, much more so than what the [#1765 merge](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/1765) allows for.

---

> ### Update Apr 2020
>
> Docker Compose v3+ [deprecated the `extends` feature](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services).

Comment: Just be aware that some Docker-aware CI services (like [Codeship's `Jet` beta](http://documentation.codeship.com/private/docker/docker/services/#unavailable-features)) do not support the `extends` directive, so this may not be an option.

Comment: Unfortunately the Docker people have not propagated the extends feature from docker-compose version 2 into d-c version 3, at least not yet, so that reduces the utility here somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

Nice clear examples, however this did not initially work for me until I updated the base.yml to call the ash shell.

**base.yml**

```
base:
    image: busybox
    command: ash -c 'echo "${WHO:-Simon} says, \"${SHOUTOUT:-Silence is golden.}\""'
```